Defining a custom function
The Problem
Define a function $f:\mathbb{R\times R\rightarrow R}$ which satisfies the following properties:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,k)}{\partial x}=0\text{ at }x=0$$
$$\forall k\in\mathbb{R}:f(1,k)=1$$
$$\forall x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}f(x,k)=x$$
The function also has to possess $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ smoothness, i.e, it should be infinitely differentiable, with respect to the first variable.

The Context
I figured that anyone with a graphing calculator can go about plotting graphs, if the equation for it is given (at least for most well-behaved equations). However, creating a custom function, given only a sketch of how its plot should look seemed interesting.
My target was a function $f(x,k)$ with $k$ being a tunable parameter. Its plot had to look like this:
Basically, the function is anchored at the point $(1,1)$, has a slope of $0$ at $x=0$, and increasing the value of $k$ makes it look closer to $y=x$.

An Example
$$f\left(x,k\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-k}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)$$
This was a function that I came up with. Here's the Desmos graph.

Finally
I am looking for more functions that satisfy the given criteria, hoping that they will lead to more insight into this graph-to-function type of problems. While functions related to the example case are OK of course, I am looking for more ways to approach the question at hand.

@whpowell96 I’m sure you meant $1-\sqrt{\epsilon+1}+\sqrt{\epsilon+x^2}$ ?

Here's a construction of a family of examples that illustrates ideas useful for other problems of this type.
To satisfy the first condition it's enough to find a (differentiable) function even in $x$, then the third condition suggests considering functions of the form
$$f(x, k) = \sqrt{g(k) + h(k) x^2}$$
satisfying $\lim_{k \to \infty} g(k) = 0, \lim_{k \to \infty} h(k) = 1$. Finally, the second condition then $h(k) = 1 - g(k)$, giving the family
$$f(x, k) = \sqrt{g(k) + (1 - g(k)) x^2} .$$
subject to the constraints

$g(k) \in (0, 1]$ for all $k$ (so that the function is defined and smooth on $\Bbb R^2$) and
$\lim_{k \to \infty} g(k) = 0$.

Functions of this form additionally satisfy $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x, k) = |x|$ for all $x$ (and not just $x \in [0, 1]$), and $f(0, k) = \sqrt{g(k)}$ .
One choice is $g(k) = \operatorname{sech}^2 k$, so that
$$f(x, k) = \sqrt{\operatorname{sech}^2 k + \tanh^2 k \cdot x^2} .$$

+1, this is truly amazing. It was something of a hit-and-trial for me, but this is… something else. Thanks a lot.

More generally, we can use $f(x,k)={(g(k)+(1-g(k))x^{n})}^{(1/n)}$ right? For any even natural $n$?

@SohamSaha Yes, and there are lots of ways to generalize the $f$ in my answer. For example, we can freely modify any $f$ that satisfies the condition by adding a smooth function that vanishes on any strip ${(x, k) : -\epsilon < x < 1 + \epsilon}$, $\epsilon > 0$, since the conditions only concern what happens on that strip.

Yes, understood. Thanks again.

Is there any particular name for this "graph sketch-to-function" type of problems? Any search term?

Not that I know.
